# Page route is not working when migrated from .NET Core 3.1 to .NET 6

Tags: .net, .net-core, migration

Issue: in our project we have added some routes via "RazorPageOptions" property.

```
builder.Services.AddRazorPages().WithRazorPagesRoot("/Features").AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
{
     options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/TestPage/TestOptions", "/nav/admin/testoptions");
});
```

Whenever I am trying to run the project this page is going to other view components which are not related to this page.

Here is the `.cshtml` markup which is inside the page:

```
@page
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>TEst page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Test</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is the `.cs` page code:

```
 public class TestOptions : PageModel
 {
        public TestOptions()
        {
            var assemblyLocation = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
            AssemblyModified = $"{new FileInfo(assemblyLocation).LastWriteTimeUtc:MMM-dd-yy hh:mm tt UTC}";
            AssemblyVersion = $"v{System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(assemblyLocation).FileVersion}";
        }

        public void OnGetAsync()
        {
        }

        public string AssemblyModified { get; private set; }
        public string AssemblyVersion { get; private set; }
}
```

Note: if I remove the html tags from the `.cshtml` page, this problem does not appear. I do not know why it is happening.

Please help me if anybody has any solution for it.

Updated:
I tried a lot of things and at last I came to know that this is happening due to "view components" used inside our project.
we are using "view components" inside which resides in "components" folder(not usual location mentioned or suggested by Microsoft), and we are using these components using "tag helpers".
If I remove the lines of code inside "_viewImport.cshtml", the first page is loading fine without any exception. As soon as I put the tag helper inside "_viewImport.cshtml" it gives me runtime exception.
the best part is the first route which is loading the page does not have any "view components". I do not know why and how those routes is been called at the time of running the application.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you could provide a minimal viable set of code files that demonstrate your issue, that would go a long way to being able to find the root cause.  It seems there are too many unknowns right not to offer any advice.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the PreferExactMatches attribute on the Router component?

Like:

```
<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly" PreferExactMatches="true">
```

Comment: mine is not razor app its a normal app. although I tried but it did not work.